# Custom animation transition for Android

Tags: android, android-animation

I have started working on the app and I would like to add some nice animation. I have seen some transitions where it has fade in effects, left to right ect.
But can anyone tell me what should I use or where to start to develop animations like this?

[Sample GIF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p4P71.gif)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's **Shared** or **Scene animation** in which you can share `component` from one `activity` to another `activity` or `fragment` to `fragment`

here is official [docs](https://developer.android.com/training/material/animations.html#Transitions) and simple [example](http://www.androidauthority.com/using-shared-element-transitions-activities-fragments-631996/)

Comment: Thanks for that, I will look up these docs. From what I see it looks like its what I am looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use these links. It may be help you.
https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Shared-Element-Activity-Transition
http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/introduction-to-the-new-lollipop-activity-transitions--cms-23711
https://developer.android.com/training/material/animations.html

Comment: That's great, tnaks!